# How to get all table names ans schemas without loop

Tags: c#, mysql

I have to retrieve the names and the schemas of old tables for creating the new tables in new database within a program. I wrote this procedure which is working. In first part I get the names of tables and store it in MyArray and the in second part I put this names in query string. But in the second part I get in first read the name of table and the following data is the schema.

Is there a solution like this:(this is not working I tried :)

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SHOW * CREATE TABLE " + DbName, conn);
```

My function is there:

```
    private int CopySchemas(string pathname)
    {
        string [] MyArray = new string[11];
        int index = 0;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
        {
            using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='" + DbName+"'",conn))
            {
                    conn.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            MyArray[index] = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            ++index;
                        }
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString() + " -> " + e.Message.ToString());
                        return 0;
                    }
              }
            for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; ++i)
            {
                string tblname = MyArray[i];
                string fname = pathname  +"\\" + tblname + ".sql";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SHOW CREATE TABLE " + DbName + "." + tblname, conn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string fname = pathname  +"\\" + reader.GetValues(0) + ".sql";
                    string schema = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    File.WriteAllText(fname,schema);
                }
                reader.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Did the function throw any exceptions? Check them and append to your posting.

Comment: And, why don't you put debug statement on `fname` and `schema` before calling `File.WriteAllText`?

Comment: This function is working but I will to bypass the for loop. There is no fault in this procedure but I do 2 lectures of the table names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sawed that for each connection must have only one reader.

So I opened two connections and for each connection I associated a reader. So I don't use an array for storing the tables names I use only the second reader where I get the tables names and schemas.

Here is the code:

```
    private int CopySchemas(string pathname)
    {
        int index = 0;
        MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs);
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='" + PublicVariables.DbName + "'", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn1.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string tblname = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SHOW CREATE TABLE " + PublicVariables.DbName + "." + tblname, conn1);
                        MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader1.Read())
                        {
                            string fname = pathname + "\\" + reader1.GetValue(0).ToString() + ".sql";
                            string schema = reader1.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            File.WriteAllText(fname, schema);
                        }
                        reader1.Dispose();
                        ++index;
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString() + " -> " + e.Message.ToString());
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
     }
```